# python apply a function on sliding window

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

I have created yield function and my dataframe is in half hourly timestep. I have already selected specific time of day I want to use this function.

For each half-hour, I need to use a sliding window of +/- 15 to select half-hours with timestamps within times of day of 22:00-02:30 and 10:00-14:30. I am not sure how to apply it to +/-15 days sliding window. I also have DOY column if that helps. I also tried "shift" in function. but looks like shift does not work in apply function

def yield(df):

```
if (df['TIME'] >="10:00:00") and (df['TIME'] <= "14:30:00") or (df['TIME'] >= "22:00:00") and (df['TIME'] <= "2:30:00"):
    return 0.85*df["A"]/(df["B"]+df["C"])
else: 
    return 1
```

df['output'] = df.apply(yield, axis = 1)

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort.  Please provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, couple things:

1. It's bad practice to name your function `yield()`, since `yield` is a reserved keyword in python.
2. Secondly, your code is unnecessarily cluttered - I rewrote it:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import NewType, List, Tuple

Dataframe = NewType("pandas dataframe obj", pd.Dataframe)


time_tup = lambda s: sum(list(s.strip().split(':')[:-1]))


def sliding_window(df: Dataframe, ranges: List[Tuple[str,str]])-> float:
    tm = time_tup(df['TIME'])
    for low, high in ranges:
        l, h = time_tup(low), time_tup(high)
        if l <= tm <= h: return 0.85 * df["A"]/(df["B"]+df["C"])

    return 1

...

sliding_window(your_df, [("10:00:00", "14:30:00"),("22:00:00", "2:30:00")])
```

I'm not sure why you want a sliding window, since simple equality tests (i.e <= and =>) get you the same answer - if you explain this in the comments I can help you more with that part. This seems sufficient for what you described, however.